# Valgrind warns of overlap when trying to copy a string into a struct member variable

Tags: c, string, multithreading, memory-management, valgrind

This is how the struct looks like for reference:

```
struct thread_data {
    struct ringbuf_t *rb;
    char *file_name;
};
```

I need to take command line arguments and store it inside struct member variables for each `thread_data` element in the `threads` array, like so:

```
for (int index = optind; index < argc; index++) {
        threads[length].rb = rb;
        memmove(&threads[length].file_name, &argv[index], strlen(argv[index]));
        strcpy(threads[length].file_name, argv[index]);
        ++length;
    }
```

Prevously used `memcpy` and it worked when I printed the variable. However, Valgrind is giving me this:

```
==465645== Source and destination overlap in strcpy(0x1fff000b54, 0x1fff000b54)
==465645==    at 0x4C3C180: strcpy (vg_replace_strmem.c:523)
==465645==    by 0x400F85: main (bytemincer.c:55)
```

So I used `memmove` and I still got the same Valgrind result. Any solution for this?

Comment: Are you sure you want to copy to `&threads[length].file_name` and not to `threads[length].file_name`? The `char *file_name;` member is a pointer.

Comment: ...and the same problem for the second argument. And why do you follow up the memmove with a strcpy?

Comment: @WeatherVane I want to copy the actual value of argue[index]. Isn't `memmove` moving the bytes, so I would need the address of where that variable is located?

Comment: That struct member is an address, not an array. You can't want to overwrite the 4 or 8 byte pointer with a string, that might be any length.

Comment: @ikegami Maybe I'm confused with what `memmove` does. Any elaborations?

Comment: To copy the value of `argv[index]` (a pointer aka an address), all you need is `threads[length].file_name = argv[index];`. But if you want to copy the pointed chars from one buffer to another, then you want `memmove(threads[length].file_name, argv[index], strlen(argv[index]));` or `strcpy(threads[length].file_name, argv[index]);`

Comment: You should remove both the `&` address-ofs from the `memmove` call. Those parameters are already addresses.

Comment: Similarly `argv[index]` is a pointer. `argv[]` is an array of pointers. What were you doing with `memcpy` when it apparently worked? You should call `memmove` in just the same way. It does the same as `memcpy` but for overlapping data.

Comment: It's not 100% clear what you are trying to do, which is makes it difficult to give a proper answer. Are you trying to copy the pointer, or are you trying to make a (modifiable) copy of the argument?

Comment: @ikegami when I only use `memmove` and not `strcpy`, it seg faults.

Comment: I would expect that, yes. Please answer question in previous comment

Comment: @ikegami let's say I have a file that I want to use and I provided it in the cmd line as `file1.txt`, I want to store that string in `threads[length].file_name` AS `"file1.txt"`

Comment: Short answer: Just `threads[length].file_name = argv[index];` (which is equivalent to just the `memmove` you have). Also, best to make it a `const char*`

Comment: Yes, because `threads[length].file_name` has to point to something to use `strcpy` or `memcpy` or `memmove`. Did you reserve memory for it?

Comment: @ikegami make the member variable `const char*` or `argv[]` ?

Comment: `thread_data.file_name`. Makes it clearer that you shouldn't free it or change it. (Might be safe to change, but not sure. But definitely shouldn't free it.)

Comment: @ikegami actually setting my member variable to `const char*` worked and I didn't even need to allocate memory or move bytes. How is that so?

Comment: @WeatherVane No I didn't reserve any memory. If I set it to `const char *`, would I still need to?

Comment: You can't copy data to an uninitilised pointer (no memory allocation), but you can make a copy of the source pointer. If your `memcpy` version was working, why is the simple change to `memmove` causing trouble? There is no difference apart from being able to handle overlapping data.

Comment: @WeatherVane it was causing trouble in valgrind, saying that `strcpy` was overlapping

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as text, the shortest *complete* code that shows what you have tried, it's not easy to say what else you are doing wrong.

Comment: @WeatherVane I mean that is what my question was originally?

Comment: The post has become confusing. The question says "Prevously used **memcpy** and it worked when I printed the variable." All you need to do is change `memcpy` to `memmove`. Anything else going wrong can't be easily seen from the code snippets.

Comment: Re "*I didn't even need to allocate memory*", Because there's no issue with having two pointers pointing to the same memory.

Comment: For precision in my illustration, is `threads` a pointer (`struct thread_data*`) or an array (`struct thread_data[...]`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you want to end up with:

(I'm using "fn" instead of "file_name" in the post.)

```
                                      *(argv[0]) @ 0x2000
                                      +---+---+- -+---+
                     +--------------->|   |   | … | 0 |
argv @ 0x1000        |                +---+---+- -+---+
+---------------+    |            
| 0x2000      -------+                *(argv[1]) @ 0x2100
+---------------+                     +---+---+- -+---+
| 0x2100      -----------+----------->|   |   | … | 0 |
+---------------+        |            +---+---+- -+---+
| 0x2200      -----------)----+
+---------------+        |   |        *(argv[2]) @ 0x2200
| ⋮             |        |   |        +---+---+- -+---+
                         |   +------->|   |   | … | 0 |
rb @ 0x3000              |   |        +---+---+- -+---+
+---------------+        |   |
| 0x4000      -------+   |   |        *rb @ 0x4000
+---------------+    |   |   |        +---------------+
                     +---)---)------->|               |
threads @ 0x5000     |   |   |        +---------------+
+---------------+    |   |   |    
|  +-----------+|    |   |   |    
|rb| 0x4000  --------+   |   |
|  +-----------+|    |   |   |
|fn| 0x2100  --------)---+   |
|  +-----------+|    |       |
+---------------+    |       |
|  +-----------+|    |       |
|rb| 0x4000  --------+       |
|  +-----------+|            |
|fn| 0x2200  ----------------+
|  +-----------+|
+---------------+
| ⋮             |
```

(This assumes `threads` is an array rather than a pointer to an array. This doesn't affect the rest of the post.)

All addresses are made up, of course. But you can see how more than once variable have the same address for value. Because it's perfectly fine to have multiple pointers point to the same memory block. All we need to do is copy the pointer (the address).

To copy a pointer, all you need to do is

```c
dst = src;
```

So all you need is

```
threads[length].rb = rb;
threads[length].fn = argv[index];
```

While

```c
memmove(&threads[length].rb, &rb,          sizeof(threads[length].rb));
memmove(&threads[length].fn, &argv[index], sizeof(threads[length].fn));
```

and

```c
memmove(&threads[length].rb, &rb,          sizeof(rb));
memmove(&threads[length].fn, &argv[index], sizeof(argv[index]));
```

are equivalent to the assignments, it doesn't make sense to do something that complicated:

(Note the use of `sizeof(argv[index])` rather than `strlen(argv[index])`. It's the pointer we're copying, so we need the size of the pointer.)

The warning came from trying to copy the string that's in the buffer at 0x2100 into the buffer at 0x2100. Remember that `threads[length].fn` and `argv[index]` both have the same value (address) after the `memmove`.